# Is there a way to create a websocket client inside a java app to communicate with a node.js websocket server?

Tags: java, node.js, spring, jsp, websocket

Currently, I'm working on a java spring app that runs on a tomcat server and I want to create a WebSocket client there to communicate with a node.js websocket server that running locally. I can't find any implementation for the client. The client has to be inside the view (.jsp file) or in a controller?
The websocket client has to be inside the web app.

Here is the implementation of the node.js server:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').createServer(app);

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server:server });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    console.log('A new client Connected!');

    ws.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
    ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    
        const array = new Int16Array(message);
        
        //console.log(array);
        console.log(new Date().toLocaleString().replace(',',' ')+" " + ' Data received');
        ws.send('The server received the message!'); 
    });
});
server.listen(3000, () => console.log(`Lisening on port :3000`))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use js, you should use WebSocket js obj to implement it. And there are more samples online. I guess you want to build a websocket client in java. So you can ref [this](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) to build client. The below is simple demo.

maven dependency

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.java-websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>Java-WebSocket</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

websocket client

```java
public class MyWebSocketClient extends WebSocketClient {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyWebSocketClient.class);

    public MyWebSocketClient(URI serverUri) {
        super(serverUri);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(ServerHandshake arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LOGGER.info("------ MyWebSocket onOpen ------");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClose(int arg0, String arg1, boolean arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LOGGER.info("------ MyWebSocket onClose ------{}",arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Exception arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LOGGER.info("------ MyWebSocket onError ------{}",arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LOGGER.info("-------- receive data from websocket server： " + arg0 + "--------");
    }
}
```

define a bean to use

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebSocketApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(WebSocketApplication.class, args);
    }

        @Bean
    public WebSocketClient webSocketClient() {
        try {
            MyWebSocketClient webSocketClient = new MyWebSocketClient(new URI("ws://127.0.0.1:3000/connection"));
            webSocketClient.connect();
            return webSocketClient;
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
   
}
```

In a restController to invoke

```java
@RestController
public class WebSocketController {

    @Autowired
    private WebSocketClient webSocketClient;

    @RequestMapping("subscribe")
    public String subscribe() {
        webSocketClient.send("hello sever，i want subscribe data A");
        return "send ok";
    }
}
```

Comment: Because I am new to all these and my app starts when I start the Tomcat server instead of running as a java application(or with the spring boot app), so where should I implement the @Bean that you mentioned? Thanks

Comment: I put the @Bean inside the rest controller and the connection worked. Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: You can use ‘@Configuration’ to define a new class in which you put ‘@Bean’. Here is a ref [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-core-annotations). see 2.7. wish helpful to u.

Comment: If I want the client to receive from the server binary data (e.g. an array(1024), an array of integers) instead of a string message, how should I implement that? Do you have any idea how to modify this code to receive binary data? Thanks again!!

Comment: You should use com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper to transfer array to string, vice versa. please ref [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)

Comment: By saying that i want the client to receive binary data I mean for example to receive frames from the server. Each frame is coded as a byte[1024] array (Int16Array). The server sends many frames and the client receives them and saves them somehow (maybe in one array). The main goal is to save all the frames in one binary file to the database as blob, but for now, I just want the first part, to receive and save the frames somehow in one string or array. This step makes me confused.

Comment: I do a simple demo sending array data. pls see [here](https://github.com/jacky-neo/websocket-demo). more info please see JAVA-WebSocket of github I mentioned. hope it helpful you.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll give it a try!!